# On linux, how to wait for multiple child processes?

Tags: linux, process, fork, wait

The *nix wait() and wait_pid() works in demo programs where

> (1) a father forks a child, wait for the child to exit
>
> (2) and the wait function returns.

It's emphasized that, if father doesn't wait and keep running, children exits and will be "Zombies".

But the real world *nix programming is like

> (1) I am writing a server program,
>
> (2) the main process works to fork some child workers,
>
> (3) and these child workers do some job and then exit.

Then question is, how do father process fork and wait for multiple children? Is there a convenient way to do this, or the design should be sth different?

Thanks.

Comment: Have you read `man wait`/`man waitpid`?

Comment: The father doesn't need to wait for its children.  It can simply have a signal handler to catch SIGCHILD and the handler can take the necessary action.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

three possibilities:

1)
Periodically check for dead children with waitpid. Ie now and again do:

```
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
        continue;
```

2) 
Cleanup in a signal handler

```
/* SIGCHLD handler to reap dead child processes */
static void grimReaper(int sig)
{
    int savedErrno = errno;
    while (waitpid(-1, NULL, WNOHANG) > 0)
        continue;
    errno = savedErrno;
}   
int main(void) {
    ...
    struct sigaction sa;
    memset(&sa, 0, sizeof sa);
    sigemptyset(&sa.sa_mask);
    sa.sa_handler = grimReaper;
    if (sigaction(SIGCHLD, &sa, NULL) == -1)
        ...
}
```

3)
Make detached children by ignoring `SIGCHLD` in the parent:

```
signal(SIGCHLD, SIG_IGN);
```

Comment: With the latter being popular for the scenario you suggest.